# How do I not show the paste bar / Clear the clipboard?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm writing a Silverlight+XNA game and when the user has something in their clipboard they can see less of the screen. I'd really like to be able to not show this clipbaord but I can't see any way (though it does seem to go away after some amount of time)

I've tried an empty string and Clipboard.SetText(null) but that throws an exception.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to either clear the clipboard from code or influence the display of the SIP beyond setting an InputScope.

The best you can do for now is to update your design to allow for the amount of space which the SIP may use. :(

Answer (score 0):

While more complicated, you could create your own text input keys as buttons, and instead of using a textbox, use buttons templated to look like textblocks, with background as you show above, and all...  When the user taps the "button" that is a "textblock", you set a flag that says which textblock the keypad buttons send their numbers to.

Or, if the only spot you are sending inputs to (as it appears now that I look at your UI again), there is no need for the button template as the input space, or the flag.  Just create buttons for user to tap for input, and send that input to the textblock that appears to be where your answer is.  You could make the buttons whatever size you want, that way, as well, so you control how much of the screen is visible.  Another thing you could do is make the buttons semi-transparent, so you could have even more background image showing.

Another thought - send the buttons all to the same event handler (except the backspace button), and have the code for that event handler look like this:

```
{
   Button btn = sender as Button;
   textblock.Text += btn.Content;
}
```